# According to the Book of Mormon, D&C, Pearl of great price and/or prophets, what prohibits lust?

Tags: lds, sexuality, book-of-mormon, doctrine-and-covenants, pearl-of-great-price

What does the Book of Mormon, Doctrine and Covenants, Pearl of Great Price, or prophets say about the prohibition of lust as a sin?

Comment: @curiousdannii I'd say not really—the kind of verse searches we generally exclude are "What's this verse I'm thinking of but forgot the reference for?" This requires a more than a keyword search, you need some domain expertise to how these books address the topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The LDS believe in [chastity](https://www.lds.org/topics/chastity?lang=eng) or in being sexually pure. The [Law of Chasity](http://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Chastity%2C_Law_of) describes the commandment to not commit adultery, or to lust.

Scriptures from Doctrine and Covenants:

- [D&C 42:22-23](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/42.22-23?lang=eng#21) - lust causes you to lose the Spirit and deny the faith
- [D&C 59:6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/59.6?lang=eng#5) - don't commit adultery or anything like unto it
- [D&C 63:16](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/63.16?lang=eng#15) - lust, or adultery in the heart, loses the Spirit

Scriptures from the Book of Mormon

- [3 Nephi 12:28](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/3-ne/12.28?lang=eng#27) - lust is adultery in the heart
- [Alma 39:9](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/alma/39.9?lang=eng#8) - don't go after lust of eyes

Scriptures from Pearl of Great Price

- [Article of Faith 13](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/a-of-f/1.13?lang=eng#12) we believe in being [chaste](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chaste)

Prophetic teachings

- [We Believe in Being Chaste](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/2013/04/we-believe-in-being-chaste?lang=eng) by Elder David A Bednar
- [Personal Purity](https://www.lds.org/liahona/1999/01/personal-purity?lang=eng) by Elder Jeffrey R Holland

Answer (score 0):

Jacob 2-3 has a rather long sermon about polygamous unions in early nephite culture being sinful, under the assumption that the husbands loved their wives less for the practice, and were primarily using the institution of marriage to satisfy their lust. These chapters talk extensively about how Solomon and David's polygamous relationships were sinful in the sight of the lord....

Despite the fact that D&C plural marriage 132 explicitly supports David's and Solomon's polygamous practices. There appears to be a contridition in LDS canonical text on this matter, as the Book of Mormon could be seen to declare that polygamous relations are sinful, with the implication that they are lustful rather than loving in nature, where D&C says the opposite.

Alma chapter 39 is a long chastisement against a Corianton, a man who abandoned his mission for sexual sin. Verse 5 specifically mentions that sexual sin is "...an abomination in the sight of the Lord; yea, most abominable above all sins save it be the shedding of innocent blood or denying the Holy Ghost?"

This verse is very notably references by many LDS leaders, and informs many LDS cultural attitudes on the severity of sexual sins.